# can't run benchmark using ApacheBenchmark on REST web application

Tags: benchmarking, apachebench

I want to benchmark two simple REST web frameword (RESTlet and RESTfulie) using ab 
I deployed a really simple app using both framework (a hello world) then I tried to run this command :

```
ab -n 1000 -c 1 http://localhost:8080/
```

but I always get this error :

> Benchmarking localhost (be patient)...apr_pollset_poll: The timeout
>   specified ha s expired (70007)

can anyone tell me please what is my problem? 
or what kind of benchmark tool I can use for testing REST web app I guess ab has allergy to REST becuase its work flawlessly on apache/php server.